# Array sum that I got from a for loop returns NaN (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, return, nan

That function below returns **NaN** instead of expected **4**. I bet there's some obvious mistake, but I'm not seeing it.

```
function myFunction(arr) {
    let arrSum = 0
    for (let i=0; i<=arr.length; i++) {arrSum += arr[i];}
    return arrSum;
}
const myArr = [2,2];
console.log(myFunction(myArr));
```

Comment: Arrays have zero-based indexing. You're overflowing the array in the loop, you need `i < arr.length`.

Comment: There are functions to avoid having to consider the length of an array. e.g. [2,2].reduce((a,b)=> a+b, 0)

Answer (score 4):

you need to iterate till only `i < arr.length` arr[arr.length] will give undefined which will make your arrSum NaN.

```js
function myFunction(arr) {
    let arrSum = 0
    for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {arrSum += arr[i];}
    return arrSum;
}
const myArr = [2,2];
console.log(myFunction(myArr));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Issue**: Limiting condition of the `for` loop exceeds array size. Current array size is 2 and loop will iterate 3 times since `i<=arr.length`. So `arr[2]` will be `undefined` and it will lead to `NaN`.

**Solution**: For accessing elements in array, limiting condition should be `i < arr.length`.

Try the below code.enter code here

```js
function myFunction(arr) {
    let arrSum = 0
    for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {arrSum += arr[i];}
    return arrSum;
}
const myArr = [2, 2];
console.log(myFunction(myArr));
```